# Extract count of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a multidimensional array from a ldap search stored in `$data`:

```
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [objectclass] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 3
                    [0] => top
                    [1] => posixGroup
                    [2] => sambaGroupMapping
                )

            [0] => objectclass
            [cn] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => xxxxx
                )

            [1] => cn
            [gidnumber] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => xxxx
                )

            [2] => gidnumber
            [sambasid] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => xxxx
                )

            [3] => sambasid
            [sambagrouptype] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => 2
                )

            [4] => sambagrouptype
            [displayname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => xxxx
                )

            [5] => displayname
            [memberuid] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 2
                    [0] => xxxxx
                    [1] => xxxxx
                )

            [6] => memberuid
            [count] => 7
            [dn] => cn=xx,ou=xx,dc=xx,dc=xx
        )

)
```

I would like to extract the count of the memberuid: `[count] => 2` but i'm not able to do it correctly. I can't figoure out the structure..

I tried: `$data[0]['displayname']['memberuid']['count']` which gives me an `Illegal string offset`

Thanks for your help

Comment: `$data[0]['memberuid']['count']`

Comment: wow thank you. i tried probably about 2 hours to make it work. Wouldn't have thought that it is so simple!